# Convert JSON to MultiMap in Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am using **Scala** with **Play**. I have a **JSON** file with all the countries in the world and their respective cities. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "CountryA": ["City1","city2"],
    "CountryB": ["City1"]
}
```

I parse it accordingly:

```
val source: String = Source.fromFile("app/assets/jsons/countriesToCities.json").getLines.mkString
val json: JsValue = Json.parse(source)
```

My ultimate goal is to convert the `json` contents into a Scala **MultiMap** where the **key** is a `String` - the *country*, and the **value** is a `Set[String]` - the *cities*.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a long-winded solution that won't throw if the JSON structure doesn't match what you're expecting:

```
  val source: String =
    """
      |{
      |    "CountryA": ["City1","city2"],
      |    "CountryB": ["City1"]
      |}
    """.stripMargin

  val json: JsValue = Json.parse(source)

  import scala.collection.breakOut

  val map: Map[String, Set[String]] = json.asOpt[JsObject] match {
    case Some(obj) =>
      obj.fields.toMap.mapValues { v =>
        v.asOpt[JsArray] match {
          case Some(JsArray(cities)) => cities.flatMap(_.asOpt[String])(breakOut)
          case _ => Set.empty[String]
        }
      }
    case _ => Map.empty[String, Set[String]]
  }

  map must beEqualTo(Map("CountryA" -> Set("City1", "city2"), "CountryB" -> Set("City1")))
```

If you're confident about the structure of the JSON and don't mind using `as` (which could throw) instead of `asOpt` (which won't):

```
  val map2: Map[String, Set[String]] = {
    json.as[JsObject].fields.toMap.mapValues {
      _.as[JsArray].value.map(_.as[String])(breakOut)
    }
  }

  map2 must beEqualTo(Map("CountryA" -> Set("City1", "city2"), "CountryB" -> Set("City1")))
```

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJson#Using-JsValue.as/asOpt